# How Does Facebook's profile.php?=id Work?

Tags: php, mysql, html, facebook

I've noticed that, when going to profile pages on facebook, it directs you to the page www.facebook.com/profile.php?=id. I'm curious as to how exactly this works. I would like to make a website where users have different profiles and I think routing it through my profile.php would work the best. However, I'm not sure how to do that exactly. I'd like to direct to profile.php, but then I don't think my html and css would be taken into the equation. I know you can use php and html in the same file, but how do you direct the content generated by php to the correct divs in html? Sorry if this question is a little confusing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm curious what your php code look like?

Comment: It's pretty basic. I had just been using AJAX to direct what I was echoing from the php to the correct div.

Comment: So what is not working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web apps would have user profile records in a database, with one column reserved for its `id`. When a user goes to `www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=5`, the code in the page searches the database for a profile with an id of 5, it then displays the information for that profile by placing this data into html:

```
<div><?= $someRecordVariable ?></div>
```

Comment: Easy and quick explanation ! Good work.

Comment: As a note, it is a good idea to keep your php and html as separate as possible (no business logic within your html).

Comment: @dqhendricks: HTML Business Logic into HTML is okay, as well as having view-models and therefore models inside the view. All okay.

Comment: @hakre HTML Business Logic? Do you mean like iterations and etc? I guess when I say business logic I mean manipulating models or other variables. Mixing that kind of stuff inside of your HTML makes it much more difficult to read. Models inside of a view, yes, if you are only accessing the model data, and not performing operations on it mid HTML.

Comment: The model is the data. You don't access data of the model, but just straight the model - or you're just doing something wrong.

Comment: @hakre I guess I don't see the distinction between what you are saying, and what I am saying. A matter of semantics? What I am trying to say is, you would not do something like `$model->add(5);` in the middle of your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It uses MVC framework I believe. It will route the traffic based on the URL variables.

Here is information on how to create one: 
http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/

there are also pre-built frameworks like larvel, cakePHP and codeigniter. you should research those and fine one that best suits what you are trying to do.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need a framework of some kind which does not involve mixing your main PHP inline with HTML. Personally I like to make my own as I stay in control.

A very simple example is the use of template files (e.g. Profile-tpl.php) which you include at the end of your php which echos whatever it is you want to output according to the HTML and CSS in Profile-tpl.php.

```
    <HTML>
    ...
        <div>
            <?php echo (!empty($content)) ? $content : ''; ?>
        </div>
    ...
    </HTML>
```

My personal style of programming is routing everything through index.php with clean URLs (e.g. domain.com/p/12345 -> index.php?page=p&id=12345), loading modules according to the query (I've established that p load Profiles) and then loading appropriate formatting from template files.